# Align with respect to symbol, not \substack

Tags: align, substack

Suppose I have a multiline equation involving some accumulation (e.g. `\sum` or `\bigcup`), where the conditions require some multiline description. Consider the following dummy example:

```
\begin{align*}
  a + b &= \sum_{\substack{i=1\\3<4}} e^\pi && \text{Some exposition.} \\
        &= \sum_{\substack{p \in \mathbb{N}\\p > 1 \land \forall a,b > 1: ab\neq p}} p
                && \text{Some more exposition.} \\
        &= b + a &&\\
\end{align*}
```

Which gives:

[image: Result]

The `align` considers the whole sum, including the substack, and because not all substacks have the same width, the sums don't line up very nicely. How can I align the equation such that the `\sum`-symbols line up with each other, but the substack is still used to offset against the `=` symbol before?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use either a `\mathclap` or a `\smashoperator` directive. Both macros are provided by the `mathtools` package.

[image]

Do effects produced by `\mathclap` or a `\smashoperator` tend to be quite similar. However, the macros aren't pure substitutes for one another. Do peruse the user guide of the `mathtools` package for more information about both commands.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}   % for \mathbb macro
\usepackage{mathtools} % for \mathclap and \smashoperator macros
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  a + b 
  &= \sum_{\substack{i=1\\3<4}} e^\pi && \text{Some exposition.} \\
  &= \sum_{\mathclap{\substack{p \in \mathbb{N}\\
         p > 1 \land \forall a,b > 1 : ab\neq p}}} p
     && \text{via \texttt{\string\mathclap}} \\[0.5ex]
  &= \smashoperator{\sum_{\substack{p \in \mathbb{N}\\
         p > 1 \land \forall a,b > 1 : ab\neq p}}} p
     && \text{via \texttt{\string\smashoperator}} \\
  &= b + a &&\\
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Aside: I obviously can't tell you how you should write the *mathematics* part of your paper. Nevertheless, I can't help but comment that stating `p > 1 \land \forall a,b > 1 : ab\neq p` below the summation symbol seems like *way too much information* to tuck away in such an inauspicious place. I wouldn't call it a masterpiece of clear communication...  I strongly suspect that your readers would very much appreciate a more elaborate explanation of what the summation is all about.

Comment: Thanks! It was just a dummy example - you'll have to forgive me for not putting my homework online ;-)